# The Schrodinger representation on the space of sections of a general  $(1,3)$-polarized abelian surface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties

This question arose while I was studying some finite covers of abelian surfaces.

Let $(A, \mathscr{L})$ be a $(1,3)$-polarized abelian surface over the complex numbers and consider the vector space $H^0(A, \mathscr{L})\cong \mathbb{C}^3$. If $A$ is *simple*, then the linear system $|\mathscr{L}|$ is base-point-free, hence its general element is smooth by Bertini theorem.

Let us consider now the Heisenberg group 
$$\mathscr{H}_3:=\{(k, \, t, \, l) \mid k \in \mathbb{C}^* , \, t \in
\mathbb{Z}/3 , \, l \in \widehat{\mathbb{Z}/3} \}$$
whose group law is 
$$(k,  t,  l)\cdot (k',  t',  l')=(kk'l'(t),  t+t', 
l+l').$$ 
By [Birkenhake-Lange, Complex Abelian Varieties, Chapter 6] there exists a canonical representation,
known as the *Schrodinger representation*, of $\mathscr{H}_3$ on
$H^0(A, \mathscr{L})$, where the latter space is identified with the
vector space $V:=\mathbb{C}(\mathbb{Z}/3)$ of all complex valued functions $f \colon \mathbb{Z}/3 \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$.

Such an action is given by
$$ (k, t, l)f(x)=kl(x)f(t+x).$$

Finally, let $X,  Y, Z$ be the elements in $H^0(A, \mathscr{L})$
corresponding to the characteristic functions of $0,  1,  2$
in $V$, respectively.

> **Question.** Is it true that if $(A, \mathscr{L})$ is *general* then the three distinguished sections $X$, $Y$, $Z \in H^0(A, \mathscr{L})$ correspond to *smooth* curves in $|\mathscr{L}|$ which intersect *transversally*?

This seems to me reasonable, but so far I could neither find any reference nor prove it.

If possible, I would also be pleased to see any explicit example where $X$, $Y$, $Z$ are smooth and intersect transversally.

This question can be generalized in a straightforward way to the case where $\mathscr{L}$ is a polarization of type $(1,d)$, but let us consider only $d=3$ for simplicity.

Comment: For $d=5$ you get Horrocks-Mumford surfaces, which (unlike the case of $d=3$) are known quite explicitly; did you try that case?

Comment: @Noam: The problem I have in mind concerns the case $d=3$, so I did not try with Horrocks-Mumford surfaces. I will, anyway. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: A question and a remark - A) why do you say that the Schrodinger representation is unique, I see # SP_2(Z/3) of them ? B) If you want to work with explicit models then all (1,3) polarized Kummer varieties are quartic surfaces with 16 lines, after you blowdown the lines (http://www.mathematik.uni-marburg.de/~tbauer/09-smkm.pdf contains more ref's than you'll need); note that the images of 1,2 are interchagned by the Kummer involution, and that the Kummer involution restrcits to an involution on the image of 0.

Comment: @david: I did not say that the representation is unique, but the one I have given should be canonical in some sense. Furthermore, it is the one I'm using for my computations. If you have time, could you please expand your nice observation in a proper answer, adding some detail on the action of the Kummer involution on the three sections? I will be glad to upvote it. Thanks!
